# TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number: float(ab[1:])

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have code like this I got an error in `float(uji[1:])`

```
    ab = []
    for fitur in self.fituruji:
        if (fitur[0] == 'F1') or (fitur[0] == 'F2') or (fitur[0] == 'F3') or (
                fitur[0] == 'F4') or (fitur[0] == 'F11') or (fitur[0] == 'F12'):
            ab.append(fitur)
    print ab

    for i, uji in enumerate(ab):
        print i, uji[1:]
        f_pd_neg = (bpf_neg[i] ** float(uji[1:])) * ((1 - bpf_neg[i]) ** (1 - float(uji[1:])))
        f_pd_pos = (bpf_pos[i] ** float(uji[1:])) * ((1 - bpf_pos[i]) ** (1 - float(uji[1:])))
        print f_pd_pos
        print f_pd_neg
```

In the uji is an array like this:

```
['F11', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1'] 
['F2', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0'] 
['F4', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0']
```

What happen I already give the float, I have no idea, and the bpf_pos is like this:

```
[0.42857142857142855, 0.5714285714285714, 0.5714285714285714]
```

And the bpf_neg:

```
[0.14285714285714285, 0.2857142857142857, 0.2857142857142857]
```

And the error is:

```
C:\Users\ACER\PycharmProjects\ProgramSkripsi\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/ACER/PycharmProjects/ProgramSkripsi/NaiveBayes.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
[0.42857142857142855, 0.5714285714285714, 0.5714285714285714]
  File "C:/Users/ACER/PycharmProjects/ProgramSkripsi/NaiveBayes.py", line 219, in <module>
    nb.BernoulliTest()
[0.14285714285714285, 0.2857142857142857, 0.2857142857142857]
[['F11', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1'], ['F2', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0'], ['F4', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0']]
  File "C:/Users/ACER/PycharmProjects/ProgramSkripsi/NaiveBayes.py", line 92, in BernoulliTest
0 ['1', '0', '0', '1', '1']
    f_pd_neg = (bpf_neg[i] ** float(ab[1:])) * ((1 - bpf_neg[i]) ** (1 - float(ab[1:])))
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

Can anyone tell me what is the problem?

Comment: Didn't I help you with this same code a few hours ago?

Comment: `ab[1:]` is a slice. You need to pass one item in aforementioned formats to `float` function.

Comment: You called the variable `uji` in the earlier question. It seems to have been deleted.

Comment: `ab[1:]` is an empty string when `ab` is `"1"` or `"0"`. What do you expect `float(ab[1:])` to return in those cases?

Comment: BTW, you can simplify `if (fitur[0] == 'F1') or (fitur[0] == 'F2') or (fitur[0] == 'F3') or (
                fitur[0] == 'F4') or (fitur[0] == 'F11') or (fitur[0] == 'F12'):` to `if (fiture[0] in ['F1', 'F2', 'F3', 'F11', 'F12']:`

Comment: Yeah thats uji I forgot, I wanna update it but I accidentally delete it sorry ,My expectation so every `bpf_neg ` squared with every fitur in `index[1:]`
for the example:
`0.428` belongs to `F11` so `0,428` squared 1 and then 0 until the end of the index, So are `0.5714` in `F2` and `0.5714` in `F4` @Barmar

Comment: Could you show what the expected result is for `F11`? I'm not sure how you're trying to combine everything.

Comment: But you need to iterate over `uji[1:]`.

Comment: Actually my problem is in uji[1:] @Barmar

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through `uji[1:]`. Something like:

```
f_pd_neg = sum(bpf_neg[i] ** x * (1 - bpf_neg[i]) ** (1 - x) for x in map(int, uji[1:]))
```